# Git command to list SHA1 hashes for all tree objects

Tags: git, tree

Using the command `git show-ref --tags` I can see all the tags and the SHA1 hashes for all these tags.

I would like a similar command for trees: a command to output all the SHA1 hashes for all the tree objects, but for nothing else.

Comment: What do you need this for?

Comment: Just exploring git objects for a better understanding of how git works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all of the objects accessible from the HEAD pointer

```
git ls-tree -r -t HEAD
```

so you can filter to find just the tree objects using `sed` or `awk`, for example,

```
git ls-tree -r -t HEAD | awk '$2 == "tree" { print $0 }'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
git rev-list --all --objects     |     # everything reachable, with path
cut -d' ' -f1                    |     # don't want the path
git cat-file --batch-check       |     # append type and size
awk '$2=="tree"'                       # just the trees
```